# How to enable SE_DEBUG_NAME on Windows 10 on a laptop?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to give my C++ program access to open another process with all rights. To do this, I need to give my current process `SE_DEBUG_NAME`.

```cpp
HANDLE hProc = GetCurrentProcess();
HANDLE hToken = NULL;
DWORD pid;

if (!OpenProcessToken(hProc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    printf("Failed to open access token\n");

if (!SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE))
    printf("Failed to set debug privilege\n");
```

I took the privilege activation function from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/secauthz/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--):

```cpp
BOOL SetPrivilege(
    HANDLE hToken,          // access token handle
    LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege,  // name of privilege to enable/disable
    BOOL bEnablePrivilege   // to enable or disable privilege
    ) 
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if ( !LookupPrivilegeValue( 
            NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
            lpszPrivilege,   // privilege to lookup 
            &luid ) )        // receives LUID of privilege
    {
        printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
        return FALSE; 
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege)
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    else
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    // Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.

    if ( !AdjustTokenPrivileges(
           hToken, 
           FALSE, 
           &tp, 
           sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), 
           (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, 
           (PDWORD) NULL) )
    { 
          printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
          return FALSE; 
    } 

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)

    {
          printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. \n");
          return FALSE;
    } 

    return TRUE;
}
```

In my case, an error `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED` occurs.

I used the `GetTokenInformation()` function, and realized that I don't have `SE_DEBUG_NAME`.

I run the program itself through Visual Studio Code. The UAC execution level requires administrator rights when the program is started.

As a result, I do not understand how I can give the `SE_DEBUG_NAME` privilege to my process.

I'm using a laptop, and a Windows 10 version. I can't set up a local security policy because I have a laptop with windows home on it
.

Comment: *"I can't set up a local security policy because I have a laptop."* - I'm unsure how to read *any* sense into that.

Comment: If it's a company-owned system that the OP doesn't actually have administrator access to then it would make sense. The fact that it's a laptop would simply be irrelevant.

Comment: UAC would be meaningless if the isolation it provides would be *that* easy to bypass.  This can only go somewhere when you run UAC elevated as well and the user accounts are in the same group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the user did not have the SE_DEBUG_NAME privilege. On my laptop, I did not find the security settings in the windows control panel. As I read, this could be due to the fact that I do not have a professional version of windows.

In general, I solved the problem by finding a [script](https://github.com/emtenet/local-security-policy/tree/master), with the help of which I provided the SE_DEBUG_NAME privilege to the user I needed.